# Getting "message": "(#324) Requires upload file" when I try to upload a picture using libcurl

Tags: facebook, libcurl, image-uploading

I want to upload a local picture file to facebook.
I use c++ so I can't use any SDK provided by facebook.
I'm using libcurl. I can post plain text to feed but can't upload picture.
Some code below:

```
char url[1024];
char data[1024];
strcpy(url,"https://graph.facebook.com/userid/photos");
sprintf(data,"access_token=%s&source=@%s&message=testPhotos",m_strAccessToken,picPath);

CURL *curl;
curl = curl_easy_init();
if(curl)
{
   curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
   curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
   curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, data);
   curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
   curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, ::ProcessResult);
}
```

picPath is where the bmp file located on the disk like "c:\file.bmp"

I always get result like this

```
  "error": {
"message": "(#324) Requires upload file", 
"type": "OAuthException", 
"code": 324
```

}

How to do this correctly?